# SQL - Conditional Selection and Row De-duplication

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables,

1. `accounts` = accounts in my app (`id`, `name`, `created_at`)
2. `accounts_history` = account change history (`history_id`, `account_id`, `history_change_date`, `field`, `status_name`)

In the `accounts_history` table there is a column that categorizes the change to an account record (`field`) that can contain two values, `field=Status` (value changed on record) or `field=Created` (Account record was created). Every `accounts` record should have a record in `accounts_history` for `field=Created`, but does not always have a record for `field=Status`.

What I am trying to query is a count of the accounts and their `field=Status` changes and if one does not exist for an `accounts` record, then default to storing the `field=Created` record and `COALESCE` the column `status_name` (Associated with `field=Status`) with the value `New`.

With my current query I retrieve a table of accounts with each associated `Status` and `Created` record, but not de-duplicated by the `field` conditional.

Should I be using a `UNION` or sub-query?

**Current Query:**

```
SELECT    accounts.id as id
        , accounts.created_at
        , accounts_history.history_id as accounts_history_id
        , accounts_history.accounts_id
        , accounts_history.history_change_date
        , accounts_history.field
        , accounts_history.status_name
FROM accounts
LEFT JOIN accounts_history
  ON accounts_history.accounts_id = accounts.id
WHERE accounts.created_at::date = date '2018-03-14' AND (accounts_history.field = 'Status' OR accounts_history.field = 'created')
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: The accounts_history conditions in the WHERE clause makes the left join return inner join result. Move those conditions to the ON clause to get true left join result.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Do you mind providing an example?

Answer (score 0):

Does field=Created update to Status or is a new entry added with field=Status? I'm guessing the latter.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (accounts.id), *
FROM accounts
JOIN accounts_history ON accounts_history.accounts_id = accounts.id AND accounts_history.field IN ('Status', 'Created')
WHERE accounts.created_at::date = date '2018-03-14'
ORDER BY accounts.id, accounts_history.id DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

FYI, didn't test this script.